# xpath selector in link text not working which i used.

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have used below code using xpath selector. but it is not working. kindly guide me who knows this issue and where i made mistake in this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class CGBrowseJobs(unittest.TestCase):
 def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "http://www.ionface.com/"
    self.verificationErrors = []

 def test_c_g_browse_jobs(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Career Grab").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Browse Jobs']/@href").click()


 def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
    return True

 def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You have included the **@href** attribute in your XPath, use this instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Browse Jobs']").click()
```

Selenium does not need to be given a link directly (like using the **@href** attribute). Give it an entire element and let it pick out the URL for you.